# Setting no-data for area outside of clip polygon with ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geotiff-tiff, clip

I need to clip black and white landuse plans which are in TIF format from a graphic in ArcGIS Desktop 10.3. or higher. The resulting black and white images should ideally be in TIF format also. The areas outside of the polygon should not be displayed. This means that the area between the envelope and the actually graphic geometry should either be defined as no-data or the color-value need to be set as transparent - which is difficult as it is black and if I define black as transparent, then I lose the lines in the landuse plan.

Does anyone know of an easy way to clip images and automatically define areas outside of the clip geometry as no-data whilst keeping the image inside the graphic geomtery as is?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why the Clip tool isn't fit for purpose? (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/clip.htm) Yes it will remove data outside the prescribed area, but if you don't require that data for display or analysis purposes, that shouldn't be an issue. You will need something to inform the clip boundary, but you mentioned a polygon so it sounds like this is already available.

Otherwise, if it is absolutely integral to retain null-value pixels in your dataset, you could Split the raster by polygon (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/split-raster.htm), use the raster calculator to set pixel values in the outside layer to null, then Merge the two rasters (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/mosaic.htm).